# Breezejs error with take(), orderBy, and inlineCount

Tags: breeze

When I call inlineCount() on a query that both orders by a related property and performs a take on the query, the inlineCount is equal to the argument passed to take(). For example, the following query returns the correct inlineCount:

```
    testFunc = function () {
        EntityQuery.from('Residents')                    
                .take(10)                    
                .inlineCount()
                .using(manager).execute()
                .then(function (data) {
                    console.log(data.inlineCount, data);  //logs correct value                      
                });
    }
```

But the when I add ordering to my query as follows:

```
testFuncOrdering = function () {
    EntityQuery.from('Residents')
            .orderBy('user.firstName')
            .take(10)
            .inlineCount()
            .using(manager).execute()
            .then(function (data) {
                console.log(data.inlineCount, data); //logs 10
            });
}
```

The inlineCount is 10, or whatever I pass to take

Here's my controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<UserDetail> Residents()
{
    return _context.Context.UserDetails
        .Where(x => _aptIds.Contains(x.User.UserDetail.ApartmentComplexId))
        .Where(x => x.Discriminator == UserDetail.Resident);
}
```

This bug seems similar to a bug that was fixed in 1.4.0, but instead of getting null/undefined for inlineCount, I'm getting the take value. If necessary, I can provide my metadata. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have confirmed your finding and reported internally as Defect #2493.  Here is my repro:

First, we know `inlineCount` works with `orderBy` and `take` at least some of the time. Here is a test from DocCode that passes:

```
var productQuery = EntityQuery.from("Products"
    .where("ProductName", "startsWith", "C");

var pagedQuery = productQuery
    .orderBy("ProductName")
    .skip(5)
    .take(5)
    .inlineCount();
```

The JSON result is:

```
{
  $id: "1",
  $type: "Breeze.WebApi.QueryResult, Breeze.WebApi",
  Results: [
    {...},
    {...},
    {...},
    {...},
  ],
  InlineCount: 9
}
```

Four products returned out a total of 9 products with names that begin with 'C'. Yes it still works without the `.skip(5)`; it returns the first 5 products and again reports a total of 9 qualifying products.

Here is the generated URL for that query:

```
http://localhost:47595/breeze/Northwind/Products?$filter=startswith(ProductName,'C') eq true&$orderby=ProductName&$top=5&$inlinecount=allpages
```

So we know Breeze does the right thing at least some of the time :)

What is going wrong for you?

It seems that the problem is with **an `orderBy` on a related entity property** (e.g., your "user.firstName").

Returning to DocCode, I revised the query URL to get `OrderDetails`, sorted by their related `Product.ProductNames`.  I didn't bother with composing the breeze query. I simply entered the generated URL into the browser address bar.

Here is the URL with the orderBy:

```
http://localhost:47595/breeze/Northwind/OrderDetails?$orderby=Product/ProductName&$top=5&$inlinecount=allpages
```

The resulting `inlineCount` is **5** ... the `take` value and the number of records actually returned.

And when I remove the `orderBy`:

```
http://localhost:47595/breeze/Northwind/OrderDetails?$top=5&$inlinecount=allpages
```

Again we get 5 OrderDetails but the resulting `inlineCount` is **2155** !!!

Houston, we have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in Breeze v 1.4.1 available now.